# no module named sip on venv

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, pyqt4, python-sip

I installed PyQt4 in python-2.7 and I have this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QPushButton("Hello World", None)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

and the error appears

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named sip
```

I already installed `Pyqt4` and `sip`(downloaded from riverbank page) with embedded local terminal in Pycharm and looking inside the folder site-package, the folder `Pyqt4` and `sip.so` are there:

[image: venv directory]

any solution of this?

Comment: try with: `pip install sip`

Comment: Already installed with pip too.